# Why JDK8's Base64 uses ISO-8859-1?

Tags: character-encoding, base64, ascii, java-8, iso-8859-1

I'm writing my own BASE64 encoder/decoder for some constrained environments.

And I found that [Base64.Encoder#encodeString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) saying that it uses `ISO-8859-1` for construct a String from those encoded bytes.

I perfectly presuming that `ISO-8859-1` charset also covers all base64 alphabets.

Is there any possible reason not to use `US-ASCII`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect it's more efficient: converting from ISO-8859-1 back to text is *just* a matter of promoting each `byte` straight to a `char`, whereas for ASCII you'd need to check that the `byte` is valid ASCII. The result for base64 will always be the same, of course.

(That's only a guess, but an educated one. You could always run benchmarks if you want to validate it...)

Comment: The code proves you right. The [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Base64.java#Base64.Encoder.encodeToString%28byte%5B%5D%29) directly delegates to [`String(byte[] ascii, int hibyte, int offset, int count)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-int-), a constructor which is deprecated because it is only useful for `hibyte==0` (read iso-latin-1) usage, for which is has an optimized copying loop. So it’s a justified and optimized usage in this specific case.

Comment: Though it would work as well if the *documentation* told it was using US-ASCII while using the same implementation. But saying “ISO-8859-1” in the documentation is a good pointer for potential implementors, hinting that using iso-latin-1 is preferred over using ASCII here…

Comment: @Holger: And it would have been very confusing for anyone *looking* at the implementation and the docs together :)

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry, I'm confused. So, `ISO-8859-1` is actually more effective than `US-ASCII` or the guy who wrote `Base64` decided to use the deprecated constructor which has nothing to do with any charset and noticed it would be great to mention `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: @JinKwon: What do you mean by "more effective"? It performs better than ASCII, and *is* ISO-8859-1 in reality.